# Xcode 10.0. how to increase sub view size inside a UIview

Tags: ios, xcode10

I have my storyboard/layout like this. inside a UIView I have a subview and a tableview. how do I increase the size of top subview in storyboard. I change the size of CheckoutNTotal but it doesn't reflect at runtime. please see attached image.[image]

Comment: How do you change size? Use constraints?

Answer (score 2):

Fix the constraint warning.  See the dotted yellow line?  That means that's the size of the view that the constraint is expecting it to be.  So since you want the view bigger, you need to tell the constraint(s) to expect it bigger.  If you tap the warning in the left pane (above what you have shown here), you can fix the warning by telling InterfaceBuilder to automatically change the constraint(s) to match the new size of the view.

Answer (score 0):

There is constraint warning, fix it.

If your view has fixed height set **Height Constraint**.

[image]